# How to get the values of one cell to the other cell in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

My data is in the first column and the third column. But I want to arrange the dataset in a certain way

[image]

In this link you can see that I want value with single * to populate in the second column but the number of occurrence will depend on the number of the blue cells in the left side. I have written this below code in VBA, but I am not getting any result !

```
Sub haridwar()
Worksheets("Data").Activate

Range("B3").Select
Dim x As Integer
x = 3

Do While ActiveCell <> Empty

If Left(ActiveCell, 2) = " * " Then
    ActiveCell.Copy
Else
    x = x + 1
End If

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

Worksheets("Result").Activate

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: you are trying to compare a 2 character string `Left(ActiveCell, 2)` to a 3 character string `" * "`  I think you want `" *"`

Comment: You also are just putting the cell in the clipboard but not pasting it anywhere.

Comment: Or rather change the two to a three to not confuse it with the possible two asterisks

Comment: @ScottCraner tried " *" but this is not working. Since you're talking about pasting the cell can you please elaborate how can i paste the cell also? I want the end results in the result page

Comment: @JvdV changed the two to three but still not working

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a formula such as the one below:

[image]

The formula should find the first value in ColA which begins with a "*" (because you're looking for an actual "*" and not using it as a wildcard, it needs to be escaped with "~") followed by a space then any other content, and is below the cell with the formula.

Just make sure the `A1:A$10000` extends beyond the end of your data.

Or using VBA:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim v, c As Range, ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, m, rngSrch As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For Each c In ws.Range("B1:B" & lastRow).Cells
        If Left(c.Offset(0, -1).Value, 1) <> "*" Then
            If Len(v) = 0 Then 'already have a label to apply?
                
                Set rngSrch = ws.Range("A" & c.Row & ":A" & lastRow)
                m = Application.Match("~* *", rngSrch, 0) 'find next label
                If Not IsError(m) Then
                    v = rngSrch.Cells(m).Value
                Else
                    Exit Sub 'no match, so no more labels to move...
                End If
                
            End If
            c.Value = v
        Else
            v = ""     'a "label" row, so reset v
        End If
    Next c
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks but I am coding this in VBA and not in excel

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do it in VBA? I am just a beginner in VBA and hence can't understand much of the code. Thanks !

Comment: If you don't understand the VBA then why not use the formula?

Comment: Because I want to code it in VBA. I know how to do it in excel. I have already written a code in VBA, but not getting the right result from it. If you know, can you please help me to find out what's wrong in that code?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't work though - if I changed it to make it work, then it would look like this...

Comment: Can't see any code here. Please share the code. Thanks !

Comment: Can anyone please help to get the right code?

Comment: I meant it would look like the code I posted - if you don't like that then I'm not sure what you're looking for.